# Conversion of 2d vector to torch::tensor doesn't have the right data in C++

Tags: c++, vector, torchscript

I'm trying to convert a 2d vectors to torch tensor in c++ but the output doesn't have the right data:

```
std::vector<std::vector <int>> indx1 = {{126, 22}, {166, 102}, {46, 46}, {166, 54} };
auto indx_options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kInt32);
auto indx = torch::from_blob(indx1.data(), {indx1.size(),2}, indx_options);
```

output:

```
 1.1586e+09  2.2036e+04
 1.1586e+09  2.2036e+04
 1.1586e+09  2.2036e+04
 1.1586e+09  2.2036e+04
[ CPUIntType{4,2} ]
```

I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I could resolve this by using arrays instead of vectors.

```
int indx1[4][2] = {126, 22}, {166, 102}, {46, 46}, {166, 54}};
auto indx_options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kInt32);
auto indx = torch::from_blob(indx1, {4,2}, indx_options);
```

output:

```
 126  22
 166  102
 46   46
 166  54
[ CPUIntType{4,2} ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).